# Problema com Checkbox ASP.NET "The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'System.Boolean' failed."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-helper

Estou tendo o seguinte problema com um checkbox

Tenho uma lista de checkbox que é carregada dinamicamente (conforme os itens que existem no banco um checkbox é gerado). Atualmente tenho apenas três itens sendo os ids 1, 2 e 3. Dentro do sistema quando eu mando salvar o objeto que contém uma lista destes itens é passado por algumas validações, e quando retorna para a View a mensagem de validação do sistema é exibida, se seleciono um  checkbox referente ao ID 2 ou 3 o  fluxo funciona normalmente, quando eu seleciono o checkbox com id 1 toda parte do backend funciona normalmente porém quando  retorna para a view e ao tentar renderizar o checkbox novamente retorna o seguinte erro:

```
 [FormatException: Cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como Boolean válido.
   System.Boolean.Parse(String value) +12394192
   System.ComponentModel.BooleanConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value) +123

FormatException: 1 não é um valor válido para Boolean.
   System.ComponentModel.BooleanConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value) +281
   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertSimpleType(CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType) +393

InvalidOperationException: The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'System.Boolean' failed. See the inner exception for more information.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertSimpleType(CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType) +541
   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.UnwrapPossibleArrayType(CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType) +258
   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertTo(Type type, CultureInfo culture) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(String key, Type destinationType) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.InputHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, InputType inputType, ModelMetadata metadata, String name, Object value, Boolean useViewData, Boolean isChecked, Boolean setId, Boolean isExplicitValue, String format, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.CheckBoxHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, String name, Nullable`1 isChecked, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +153
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.CheckBox(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String name, Object htmlAttributes) +40
   ASP._Page_Views_SolicitacaoServico_Inserir_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Projetos\VALERENDA\ValeRenda\ValeRendaMVC\Views\SolicitacaoServico\Inserir.cshtml:65
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +173
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9765045
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

CSHTML onde é gerado o Checkbox

```
<label>Ocorrências</label>
<div class="checkbox-list">
    @if (TempData["SelecionarOcorrencia"] != null)
    {
        if (((List<TipoOcorrenciaViewModel>)TempData["SelecionarOcorrencia"]).Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (TipoOcorrenciaViewModel item in (List<TipoOcorrenciaViewModel>)TempData["SelecionarOcorrencia"])
            {
                <label>
                    @Html.CheckBox("OcorrenciasSelecionadas",  new { @Value = item.TipoOcorrenciaID})
                    @item.Descricao                                                              
                </label>  

            }
        }
    }
</div>
```

View Model

```
public class TipoOcorrenciaViewModel
    {

        public int TipoOcorrenciaID { get; set; }

        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        public string Sigla { get; set; }

        public bool Ativo { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Ocorrencia> Ocorrencia { get; set; }

        public bool ExigeAnexo { get; set; }

    }
```

Vi algumas repostas relacionadas a erros parecidos porém em situações diferentes, não consigo identificar o que possa ser, já que só acontece com o ID 1 nos outros funciona perfeitamente

EDIT

---

fiz um teste removendo o item com id 1 da lista antes de renderizar
ao selecionar o primeiro checkbox da lista da o mesmo erro
ao selecionar o segundo funciona normal

Comment: Se quando você seleciona IDs 2 e 3 tudo funciona, mas somente para o ID 1 não funciona, tente comparar os campos entre esses objetos, pois parece que algum campo relacionado ao ID 1 precisa ser convertido/tratado.

Comment: Opa Renan, já havia verificado isso, mas dei mais uma olhada para desencargo de consciência e não há diferenças nos objetos só os valores dos atributos mesmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver de uma forma que não me agradou muito, foi uma solução paliativa
com base [nesta postagem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220020/how-to-handle-checkboxes-in-asp-net-mvc-forms) do StackOverflow em inglês

troquei o @Html.Checkbox pela tag input html

```
<label>
   @if (Model != null && @Model.OcorrenciasSelecionadas.Contains(item.TipoOcorrenciaID.ToString()))
   {
    <input type="checkbox" name="OcorrenciasSelecionadas" value="@item.TipoOcorrenciaID" checked>
   }
   else
   {
    <input type="checkbox" name="OcorrenciasSelecionadas" value="@item.TipoOcorrenciaID">
   }        
    @item.Descricao                                                              
</label>
```